# Qt prevent QAbstractItemDelegate ::paint() from being called for all option styles

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm looking to avoid having my custom QAbstractItemDelegate's paint() function be called for option states that I'm not interested in. Specifically, I don't wish to support any hover functionality, so I would like to not repaint while mousing over a table cell.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to disable painting for different kinds of events generically.

However, you should be able to disable painting as a result of a mouse hover by disabling mouse tracking:

```
myWidget->setMouseTracking(false);
```

[QWidget::setMouseTracking](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)